# UISlider not animating in iOS7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uislider

When I switched from iOS 6 to iOS 7 design, I noticed that using the method `setValue:animated:` no longer animates the sliding process. Has anyone else came across this problem and found a solution?

I'll just add some code to show I've done nothing complicated:

```
//Variable declaration
IBOutlet UISlider *s; //Connected in the .xib

//Button pressed
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [s setValue:1 animated:YES];
}
```

And it jumps straight to 1 after I press the button.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Backwards compatible to iOS 4 solution/workaround:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    [_sliderTest setValue:0.90 animated:YES];
}];
```

It seems that iOS 7 wont animate unless you specify both this block and animated:YES.  iOS 6.0 seems to ignore the animation block and execute its own internal block. Kinda odd. Specify a duration of 2.0 to see iOS 7 animate twice as slow as iOS 6 with the same code.

Comment: Found this solution too, completely weird! But thats the way to go!

Comment: Yea, you still need to do this in iOS8. Using either method independently doesn't work.

Comment: And, still broken in iOS 10. Workaround still works.